# equation manipulation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, differential-equations, state-space

I have a problem using MATLAB for a dynamics problem. The problem is how to code in MATLAB, not how to solve the equation. I'm fairly new to MATLAB.

I have 2 equations of motion like

DDx_c =

((k*x_c - (m_p*(2*Dtheta^2*l*sin(theta) - (2*l*cos(theta)*((m_p*sin(2*theta)*Dtheta^2*l^2)/2 + (m_p*sin(2*theta)*l^2)/2 - g*m_p*sin(theta)*l + F - b_c*x_c))/(I + l^2*m_p*cos(theta)^2)))/2)*(I + l^2*m_p*cos(theta)^2))/(l^2*m_p^2*cos(theta)^2)

and

DDtheta =

-((m_c + m_p)*(F - b_c*x_c + (l^2*m_p*sin(2*theta))/2 + (Dtheta^2*l^2*m_p*sin(2*theta))/2 - g*l*m_p*sin(theta) + (l*m_p*cos(theta)*(- l*m_p*sin(theta)*Dtheta^2 + k*x_c))/(m_c + m_p)))/(l^2*m_p^2*cos(theta)^2)

My problem is that i would like to have these equations on State Space form, in order to generate a transfer function. My problem is, that i'm not able to separate the expressions in the equation. It could be done by hand ofcause, but i would realy like this program to be generic

Could a solution be to convert the equation to a string(char array), and copy the expressions separated by '+' and '-' to some new variables, like it could be done in C++. I'm just not sure how to do it.

Comment: Why do you want to apply methods for linear DE to a DE system that is heavily non-linear?

Comment: Is this something like a spring coupled with a fulcrum? If these expressions are CAS generated, please apply `simplify` to them. In most cases a compact formulation can be found directly from the terms in the Lagrange functional or the Euler-Lagrange equations. Most transformations like linearization can also be performed more comfortably in this semi-solved state.